# Hosting a Full Node - Best Practice

Tags: iri-node, security

Hosting a full node results in some security questions.
Which API Parameters (--remote-limit-api) are necessary to accept connections from light wallets without giving them to much permission?

Comment: [Related / Duplicate](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/350/how-do-i-configure-a-public-node).